# Joining 2 objects in Blender 2.8 loses UV mapping on 1

Tags: uv

I'm a bit new at Blender, so this question might sound stupid, but I've tried every suggestion I can find here and nothing is working for this.

I have 2 separate objects with their own UV and material. I've named the materials and the UVs to be unique prior to joining them. I've made certain that both objects have both materials. But, as soon as I join them, both objects always try to use the same UV map. I've tried added vertex groups and assigning them prior and after joining, but that was no assistance, either.  Is there some basic step I am missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Blender file:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!At__F5mV_pKlgdFMYC3Ivy50t0VZZQ

Answer (score 1):

A material uses the active UV map of the object if it is not specified otherwise. If you have the UV maps named differently, they are the active UV maps for each object when they are separate, however when they are joined the one from the active object becomes the active one for all the vertices of the new mesh. If the UV maps had the exact same name, they would be merged when the objects are joined.

It is probably best to just name the UV maps same so they get merged when joining, but if there was a reason to have them separate and at some point use one texture with both of them, they could be added together with nodes and since color values in Blender are 32 bit floats, Mix Color node can be used for this even though UV maps consist of coordinates and not colors.

[image]

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If more UV maps are linked to an object, the materials used by that object need to have an ***Input > UV Map* node** attached to the *Vector* socket of their textures, specifying which UV Map to use, so either of these:

[image]